# How to bind a property containing a space(-like) character in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, bind

In the `DataContext` of my `TextBox` I have an object which exposes a property called "Name Surname".

I have tried these three possibiltie so far:

```xaml
Text="{Binding selectedEntity.Name Surname}"

Text="{Binding selectedEntity.'Name Surname'}"

Text="{Binding selectedEntity.&quot;Name Surname&quot;}"
```

None does work. Could someone provide me a working example?

EDIT:
I create the datacontext object in a powershell runspace like this:

```ps
$myObject = New-Object PSObject
$myObject | Add-Member -Name "Sure Name" -Value "test" -MemberType "NoteProperty"
```

There, I'm allowed to access the property via

```ps
$myObject.'Sure Name'.
```

Comment: Please also post the property defnition of that property.

Comment: The datacontext object is a psobject. Therefore the property I think is type of object.

Comment: I modified the title so it better fits the actual problem

Comment: Have you tried "CodeProperty" instead of "NoteProperty"?

Comment: I can not change the way, how it is created. It is so and I have to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using the space character (Unicode code point value 32) in an identifier name is not allowed.

The property name was either generated with some other unicode character which looks like a space or the class was generated in IL where identifiers can contain characters which are invalid in C#.

You should try to figure out *why* the property has that name and try to fix the naming first. If you don't know which characters are used in the generated class you are lost anyway.

XAML allows escaping special characters though. If your property name contains for example a space character (0x20) you can try with:

```xaml
Text="{Binding selectedEntity.Name&#x20;Surname}"
```

More about [Spaces in identifier names](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/17/spaces-in-identifier-names-in-c/) which may be interesting (or nightmare-inducing...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add binding from codeBehind, may serve the purpose

```
Binding mB = new Binding();
mB.Source = MyProperty;
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, mB);
myTextBlock.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: My workaround in the meantime is from code behind. The final solution should be in xaml w/o any code behind.